# How to watch ConfigMap with sharedInformer

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

How to watch changes in configMaps using sharedInformer ? I tried something and I see in log that configMaps is watched but when I change some property in configMap I still see old value:

```
@PostConstruct
public void watch() {
    SharedInformerFactory sharedInformerFactory = client.informers();
    SharedIndexInformer<ConfigMap> configMapInformer = sharedInformerFactory.sharedIndexInformerFor(ConfigMap.class,
            ConfigMapList.class, 10 * 1000L);
    configMapInformer.addEventHandler(new ResourceEventHandler<ConfigMap>() {
        @Override
        public void onAdd(ConfigMap configMap) {
            System.out.println("ConfigMap " + configMap.getMetadata().getName() + " got added");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(ConfigMap oldConfigMap, ConfigMap newConfigMap) {
            System.out.println("ConfigMap " + oldConfigMap.getMetadata().getName() + " got updated");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDelete(ConfigMap configMap, boolean deletedFinalStateUnknown) {
            System.out.println("ConfigMap " + configMap.getMetadata().getName() + " got deleted");
        }
    });

    sharedInformerFactory.startAllRegisteredInformers();
}
```

I was following [this](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md#sharedinformers) example

Comment: which version of client are you using?

Comment: we recently had a regression in 4.11.0 due to which updates were getting ignored: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/2445

Comment: But this is fixed in v4.11.1

Comment: yes you are right now it is working. I am curious when this version will be used by  spring-cloud-kubernetes-dependencies

Comment: oh, okay. Sorry for inconvenience. I can't say much about spring cloud. Maybe you can create a PR for bumping version linking the regression there...

Answer (score 0):

spring-cloud-kubernetes contributor here. This was fixed as part of [this PR](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/pull/1036). It is on `3.0.x` branch, and as such not yet released. But it will fairly soon.